# Why is the background color not changing when button press?

Tags: android, android-layout

**Problem**
Below are the xml and main activity files from a simple android program, to change the background color of the screen when the button is clicked.

**Why** is the code below generating the following error, and what is the best way to fix it? I believe it the problem is something to do with the id activity_main, but am not sure how to resolve it. I have looked at similar problems on this site with out success.

**Error**
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.RelativeLayout.setBackgroundColor(int)' on a null object reference at com.beutifultec.strobelight.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:32)

This is the line

```
bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
```

---

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.widget.RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.beutifultec.strobelight.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

---

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
public void myButtonListenerMethod() {
    Button button = (Button)findViewById(R.id.button);
    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
            int color = ((ColorDrawable) bgElement.getBackground()).getColor();
            if (color == Color.RED) {
                bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else { bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
}
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);
    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    myButtonListenerMethod();
}
```

The exact code works fine if I change the code to change the color of the button instead of the main display.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {


@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    Button bgElement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
    myButtonListenerMethod();
}

public void myButtonListenerMethod() {
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

    button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Button bgElement = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
            int color = ((ColorDrawable) bgElement.getBackground()).getColor();
            if (color == Color.RED) {
                bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLUE);
            }
            else {
                bgElement.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Comment: Try setting the id for the Relative Layout as well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add id for root view, `RelativeLayout` in this case.

```
<android.widget.RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/root_layout"           // <- Add this line here
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="com.beutifultec.strobelight.MainActivity">

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Change"
        app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.56"
        app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
        app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.498"
        tools:layout_constraintLeft_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintRight_creator="1"
        tools:layout_constraintTop_creator="1" />

</android.widget.RelativeLayout>
```

And change `RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.activity_main);` to `RelativeLayout bgElement = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.root_layout);`

This should work.

**Note: Remove the comment from the XML**